# problem with /compress

Tags: compression

I have script that was provided with some SW.
The script output is something like that (in debug mode).

```
+ changeDirectory
+ '[' -d /cdr/work/proc_raw/proc ']'
+ cd /cdr/work/proc_raw/proc
+ echo 'Changed to the directory: /cdr/work/proc_raw/proc'
Changed to the directory: /cdr/work/proc_raw/proc
+ retypeFileName
++ echo ''\''*.old'\'''
++ sed 's/'\''//g'
+ FILE='*.old'
+ case $TYPE in
+ compressFiles
+ echo 'files to compress: '
files to compress: 
+ find . -name '*.old' -mtime +3
./file1.cdr.old
./file2.cdr.old
...
+ find . -name '*.old' -mtime +3
+ xargs compress -f
+ ecode=0
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ echo 'executed: find . -name *.old -mtime +3 | xargs compress -f'
```

However, after that, when looking for the file1.cdr.old.Z, file1.cdr.old.Z, .. in that directory, the file is not there.

If to execute the `file` command, it seems that there is no reason for compress to fail:

```
-bash-3.2# file file1.cdr.old
file1.cdr.old: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: 
the relevant parts from the script:

```
# Change to the selected directory
changeDirectory (){
    if [ -d $DIRECTORY ]
    then
    cd $DIRECTORY
    echo "Changed to the directory: $DIRECTORY" >> $LOGFILE
    else
        echo "$DIRECTORY does not exists" >> $LOGFILE
        exit 1
    fi
}

# Removes the "'" characters from filename.
retypeFileName (){
   FILE=$(echo $FILE | sed s/"'"//g )
}
# COMPRESSING FILES
compressFiles () {
   echo "files to compress: " >> $LOGFILE
   find . -name "$FILE" -type f $ACTION_TYPE +$PARAM >> $LOGFILE

   find . -name "$FILE" -type f $ACTION_TYPE +$PARAM | xargs compress -f
   ecode=$?

    if [ $ecode -gt 0 ]
    then
        dt=`date "+%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S"`
        echo "$dt > ERROR while compressing files. Error Code was $ecode" >> $LOGFILE
        exit 2
    fi

    echo "executed: find . -name "$FILE" -type f $ACTION_TYPE +$PARAM | xargs compress -f" >> $LOGFILE
}
```

Comment: Post the original script, not the debug output

Comment: sorry, I can't paste it all, but I'll paste the relevant parts of it

Comment: If you call `compress file1.cdr.old`, what happens?

Comment: Also what happens when you run commands such as `locate compress` or `whereis compress`. At this point I would be suspicious that compress is either not on the system or not on your $PATH. Also was this s/w run by someone else previously, and you're now running it? Perhaps `compress` is part of their environment but not yours.